# How to loop through JSON object with an array with backslashes inside in Jquery/Javascript from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array where I want to loop through the array inside the JSON and show the data in the table based on the nationalities in the array. The problem is that the array data contains backslashes and I can't loop through it. I retrieve the data with an AJAX call from my PHP file.

PHP:

```
$arr 

if (!empty($arr)) {
        echo json_encode($arr);
      // print_r($arr);
    } else{
        $errors = 'No data available.';
    }
            exit;
```

If I  print_r() I see: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [company] => John Comp [pro_countries] => ["BR","ES","FR"])`

If I use echo json_encode my echo looks like but I can print company in my Jquery: `[{"company":"John Comp","nationality":"[\"BR\",\"ES\",\"FR\"]"}]`

But if I use print_r($arr) the slashes disappear but I can't seem to print the company in Jquery: `[{"company":"John Comp","nationality":"["BR","ES","FR"]"}]`

If I use Print_r() Then my AJAX call in JQuery goes straight to the error response.
JQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
            url: 'testurl',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response){
            

             response.nationality.forEach((item)=>{

            });
```

I also tried:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
            url: 'testurl',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response){

var data = JSON.parse(response);

data.nationality.forEach((item)=>{

  });
```

What I want after the loop:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`nationality` is a JSON string, you need to parse it so you can loop over it.

```
JSON.parse(response.nationality).forEach(item => ...)
```

I'm not sure why you encoded `nationality` in the first place. You should just make it an ordinary PHP array, and then it will be encoded as part of `$arr`.

Comment: If i use print_r instead of json_encode it goes to the error response in my Ajax call

Comment: I wasn't talking about `json_encode($arr)`. Something earlier in the script is doing `$arr['nationality'] = json_encode($nationalities);`

Comment: My bad it was just a typo when I made this post. It should be without at the top, I fixed it

Comment: The error still stands, any idea ?

Comment: Your edit is not valid PHP. You can't put `"` inside a quoted string without escaping them.

Comment: Look at my new edit. When I use print_r($arr) this is what I see

Comment: Use `var_dump()` rather than `print_r()`. `print_r()` doesn't show the quotes around strings, so you can't tell the difference between an array and the string representation of an array.

Comment: But the json_encode output is clear. nationality is a string containing nested quotes, that's why they're escaped.